# how to change sql query to laravel model query without DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, model

i am going to change sql query to laravel model query without DB.
DB means `illuminate\Fascade\DB`;

```
   ->join(array(\DB::expr('(select SUM(p.amount) as paid, p.case_id
                        from payments p
                        where p.status_id = 3
                        group by p.case_id)'),'p'), 'LEFT')->on('p.case_id','=','c.id')
```

this is sql query of fuelphp.
i want to change it with laravel model style.
how can i convert?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite difficult guess your whole sql query but in general you need two models. You need [create relations between them](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#introduction) and then you can use Eloquent.

For example have two models (read tables) - users and payments:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function payments(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Payment::class);
    }
}

class Payment extends Model
{
    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Then you can create Eloquent query:

```
Payment::with('user')->where('status_id', 3)->sum('amount')
```

Comment: i want to make alias for subquery.
then, we may think subquery is just other table and realize leftjoin.

Comment: [https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-join-with-subquery-in-query-builder-exampleexample.html]